# How can i render Text inside image background in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to render a text component inside ImageBackground component.

What i tried is

```
<ImageBackground
    source={{uri: smartPaperData.backgroundImage}}
    resizeMode="contain"
    resizeMethod="scale"
    style={{
         height: '100%',
         width: undefined,
         backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    }}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

By using the above code this is what im getting. (you can see hello at the left top)

[image]

I need Hello text to come in top left of the image, but text is coming somewhere else.

Can anyone help me in sorting this out

Answer (score 0):

width is totally depend on the raw image size . you need to create container with fix width like

```
<View style={{width: '80%'}}>
   <ImageBackground
    source={{uri: smartPaperData.backgroundImage}}
    resizeMode="contain"
    resizeMethod="scale"
    style={{
         height: '100%',
         width: '100%',
         backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    }}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
</ImageBackground>
</View>
```

Comment: But how can i make such fix width for view. Since i may get either landscape or potrait image from api i need to contain fit it

Comment: when landscape just change width